# QTreeView requests index for invalid row

Tags: python, pyqt, mvp, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

Have a look at the following MWE.

It is a simple `QAbstractItemModel` with only a single level, storing its items in a list. I create a `QTreeView` to display the model, and a button to remove the 2nd item.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, QAbstractItemModel, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView, QApplication, QPushButton


class Item:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title


class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._items = []  # typing.List[Item]

    def addItem(self, item: Item):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), len(self._items), len(self._items))
        self._items.append(item)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def removeItem(self, item: Item):
        index = self._items.index(item)
        self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), index, index)
        self._items.remove(item)
        self.endRemoveRows()

    # ----- overridden methods from QAbstractItemModel -----

    # noinspection PyMethodOverriding
    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role):
        item = index.internalPointer()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item.title

    # noinspection PyMethodOverriding
    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            return len(self._items)
        return 0

    # noinspection PyMethodOverriding
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    # noinspection PyMethodOverriding
    def index(self, row: int, col: int, parent=QModelIndex()):
        assert not parent.isValid()
        return self.createIndex(row, 0, self._items[row])

    def parent(self, index=QModelIndex()):
        return QModelIndex()


def removeItem():
    model.removeItem(item2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    model = TreeModel()
    button = QPushButton('Delete')
    button.clicked.connect(removeItem)
    button.show()
    item1 = Item('Item 1')
    model.addItem(item1)
    item2 = Item('Item 2')
    model.addItem(item2)
    treeView = QTreeView()
    treeView.setModel(model)
    treeView.show()

    app.exec()
```

As far as I can tell, the implementation of my model is correct (though very basic). In particular, the row, and column counts it reports are correct, and it never creates indices for data that would not be valid.

Steps to reproduce my issue:

- Run the code above.
- In the tree view, select Item 2.
- Press the *Delete* button.

On my system, the application crashes in `beginRemoveRows()`, because the view requests a `QModelIndex` for row 2. Naturally, row 2 does not exist.

**Any idea why the `QTreeView` would think there would be 3 rows, when the model explicitly reports there are only 2?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an item is added, moved, removed, etc, what the model does is verify the QPersistentModelIndex are valid or not, so it calls the [index()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) method of QAbstractItemModel. And in that method it is the developer's responsibility to verify if the row or column is valid, and for that the model provides the [hasIndex()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#hasIndex) method that you do not use causing the error you point out, so the solution is:

```py
def index(self, row: int, col: int, parent=QModelIndex()):
    if not self.hasIndex(row, col, parent):
        return QModelIndex()
    assert not parent.isValid()
    return self.createIndex(row, 0, self._items[row])
```

Comment: This cannot be the issue here. Note that the error is raised in `beginRemoveRows`, i.e. *before* any changes to the model were made. Also, I need not worry about persistent indices, it is exactly the purpose of `beginRemoveRows` and `endRemoveRows` to deal with persistence.

Comment: @polwel You are not wrong. No error is not there, try my solution and you will see that I am right. I recommend you check the official example of Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html  And if you want to dig deeper, analyze the source code:  https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp

Comment: Ok, I was confused by a [statement in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#checkIndex): *'Note that it's undefined behavior to pass illegal indices to item models, so applications must refrain from doing so, and not rely on any "defensive" programming that item models could employ to handle illegal indexes gracefully.'* I understood this 'narrow' paradigm to include `index()` as well. Apparently it does not. `QTreeView` does not check if `row+1` is still legal when calling `index()`, so that needs be handled by the model.

Comment: @polwel Exactly, what Qt points out is that you should verify since most of the methods are not protected for that kind of errors. Due to efficiency and complexity Qt does not do it.

Comment: Huh, the docs do mention it [somewhere](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#parents-and-children): *If no valid child item - corresponding to the specified row, column, and parent model index, can be found, [index()] must return `QModelIndex()` [...]*

Comment: @polwel Exactly, in fact in my case I prefer to analyze how QStandardItemModel is implemented since it is a generic model. :-)

Comment: No, Qt points out that the model should, for performance, *not* do it. It is the responsibility of the view. Clearly `index()` is an exception to this rule. Thanks for your help though! I accepted your answer. **Edit**: didn't see your last comment before posting this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193785/discussion-between-polwel-and-eyllanesc).